# Network Performance in Win 7 - XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-xp-mode

Are there any tips and tricks for improving the performance of the Network Adapter for XP Mode?

Specifically:
I am using my XP Mode VM exclusively for browsing a web application hosted on the host Win 7 machine (for testing purposes) and it is ridiculously slow. 
Other browser traffic is **much** faster.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you could try checking the duplex settings of the network card and on the virtual network card that is being bridged to the VM.

Do you require help on how to do that?

Comment: yes please - I don't know the best way to configure duplex settings on a network card.